# Issue with rounding mode in ROUND_UP in Java

Tags: java

I want to use ROUND_UP as the rounding mode. But, when the decimals in the original number are less than three decimals, then at the end "1" is appended.

```
  int precision = 3;
  double[] values = { 1.9024999999999999, 2.1234, 2.2835, 2.04 };
  for (double value : values) {
     BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(value);
     bd1 = bd1.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
     System.out.println(value + "===========" + bd1.doubleValue());
  }
```

The output is as below -

```
1.9024999999999999===========1.903

2.1234===========2.124

2.2835===========2.284

2.04===========2.041
```

Answer (score 2):

> But, when the decimals in the original number is less than 3 decimals, then at the end "1" is appended.

Your value of 2.04 isn't *really* 2.04. It's actually 2.04000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625, which is the `double` value closest to 2.04. So when you round that up, it's being correctly rounded up to 2.041.

You're using the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor, which almost certainly doesn't do what you want it to - see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) for warnings about it. If you use [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-) instead, it will behave as you expect.

Code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int precision = 3;
        double[] values = { 1.9024999999999999, 2.1234, 2.2835, 2.04 };
        for (double value : values) {
            BigDecimal bd1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
            bd1 = bd1.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
            System.out.println(value + "===========" + bd1.doubleValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.9024999999999999===========1.903
2.1234===========2.124
2.2835===========2.284
2.04===========2.04
```

Comment: May I ask why the real value of `2.04` is that one you said?

Comment: @dabadaba: Because that's simply the closest `double` value to 2.04. The value 2.04 can't be exactly represented in binary floating point.

Comment: Yeah, I could read that. I assume that means there's no way to store a precise `2.04` in floating point?

Comment: @dabadaba: In *binary* floating point, that's right. For more about binary floating point, see http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx (It's C#-oriented, but the basic information applies to Java.)

Comment: @PoonamWaikul: Why is that a surprise? The value is more than 1.805, so it's rounding it up. Perhaps you wanted a rounding mode of `HALF_UP`? It's hard to tell as you haven't explained what you're trying to achieve.